# Fuzzy in a dictionary

Tags: dictionary, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzy

Im Ann and working for the furst time with Fuzzy. I want to match my content in a dictionray.

So its fuzzy the right methode to go this result? Or is there any other possibility i should read first?

thanks for reading and a blessed day!

The dictionary looks at the  moment like this:

```
    `enter code here`{
     `enter code here`"apetizer": [
      {
       "name": "Apple Juice",
       "type": "drink",

  },
  {
   "name": "Apple Juice Extra",
   "type": "drink",
  },
   "name": "liver",
   "type": "meat",
  }
 ],
 "afterapetizer": [
  {
   "name": "Coca Cola Zero",
   "type": "drink",
  },
  {
   "name": "Coa Cola Light",
   "type": "drink",
  },
  {
   "name": "Coca Cola",
   "type": "drink",
  },
  {
   "name": "Coca Cola Zero",
   "type": "drink",
  },
  {
   "name": "Sandwich",
   "type": "meat",
  },
  {
   "name": "Sandwich Honey Mustard",
   "type": "meat",
  },
  {
   "name": "Long mediumSandwich,
   "type": "meat",
  },
 ],

Is ist possible to work with fuzzy in this case. I want that fuzzy gives me the same dictionary structure but only within in this example one match.

Result:
{ "apetizer": [ { "name": "Apple Juice", "type": "drink", }, "name": "liver", "type": "meat", } ], "afterapetizer": [{ "name": "Coca Cola", "type": "drink", }{ "name": "Sandwich", "type": "meat", }
 ],
```

Comment: Could you provide more info here and clearly phrase what the issue is or what you need to achieve?

Comment: thanks for you comment! maybe it could be a solution. i was thinking if fuzzy is the right method! if with fuzzy its possible to search in one dictionary, and if or example three differnt kind of Coca Cola can be reduce to one value. "Coca Cola". i hope it helps for understanding :)